# Add configuration to web.config in .NET Core build/publishing

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, azure-pipelines

I have a build pipeline that builds and publishes an ASP.NET Core 3.x application.

```
# ASP.NET Core
pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

variables:
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- script: dotnet build --configuration $(buildConfiguration)
  displayName: 'dotnet build $(buildConfiguration)'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Publish to artifacts directory'
  inputs:
    command: 'publish'
    publishWebProjects: True
    arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    zipAfterPublish: True
```

The application is automatically deployed to IIS in a different process.

However, the web.config generated needs to be adjusted to disable compression:

```
<configuration>
  ...// aspNetCore stuff
  <system.webServer>
    // Add this to generated web.config
    <urlCompression doStaticCompression="false" doDynamicCompression="false" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Apart from a custom PowerShell script, is there a better way to achieve this?

**UPDATE**, this is how resulting zip is deployed to IIS:

```
steps:
- task: IISWebAppDeploymentOnMachineGroup@0
  displayName: 'Deploy IIS Website/App:'
  inputs:
    WebSiteName: '$(IISWebSiteName)'
    Package: 'PathToPublishedApp.zip'
    RemoveAdditionalFilesFlag: true
    TakeAppOfflineFlag: true
    JSONFiles: appsettings.json
```

Comment: You can use config transform and overwrite properties in `web.release.config`.
Take a look here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/transform-webconfig?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: How do you deploy it to IIS?

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk, add the deployment step to question. It is using the IISWebAppDeploymentOnMachineGroup task.